# Finding the NP test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, neyman-pearson-lemma

I am really interested on solving the following problem I found in the Casella and Berger.

Suppose we have the following pdf: 2$\theta x + 2(1-\theta)(1-x)$ where $ 0<x<1$ and  $0<\theta<1$. We are looking for the NP test where the hypothesis we look to test is: $H_0 : \theta = \theta_0$ vs $H_1: \theta = \theta_1$ , where $\theta_1 < \theta_0$ Just one observation.

We wish to find the acception region when $\alpha$ is unknown.

WHAT I HAVE DONE:

Using the NP Lemma

$\frac{f_{\theta_0}}{f_{\theta_1}} \leq K$ which implies that $2\theta_0x + 1 - x - \theta_0 -2\theta_1Kx - K + Kx + K\theta_1\leq 0$

By doing the algebra, we then have that $x \leq \frac{(\theta_0 - K\theta_1) + (K-1)}{2(\theta_0 - K\theta_1) + (K-1)}$

I then defined $K^* = \frac{(\theta_0 - K\theta_1) + (K-1)}{2(\theta_0 - K\theta_1) + (K-1)}$

To find the acception region, we seek

$\alpha = P(x\leq K^*$ when $\theta = \theta_0) = \int_{0}^{K^*}2\theta_0x+2(1-\theta_0)(1-x)dx = 2(K^*(1-\theta_0)-\frac{(K^*)^2}{2})$

First question: Is what I have done correct?

Second question: The next step is solving for $\alpha$, how should I approach such problem?

Comment: Is this for some class?

Answer (score 0):

First question: Yes.

Second question: You have to express $K^{*}$ in function of $\theta_0$ and $\alpha$.